# How should I overload member variable type in C++

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have some code I am customising for a slightly different purpose. There are slight UI changes which in this case are implemented using a new Qt form file. The UI items all have the same names, but have been rearranged. This is a given, I cannot change it.

The class using the UI needs to use the generated Qt form class, which has a different type to the original file. Let's say the original UI form class is called CarDoorForm and the new one LargeCarDoorForm. 
Let's say the class using the form UI was originally a Car class. The Car class has a private member variable _DoorForm of type CarDoorForm.  I want to modify the Car class so that it uses a LargeCarDoorForm instead of CarDoorForm.
That is fine; I end up with this:

```
class Car {
public:
  ...
  QString doorColour() 
  {
    _DoorForm.paintColourTextEdit->text();
  }

  private:
    CarDoorForm _DoorForm;
  };
};
class LargeCar : public Car()
{
   ....
   private:
   LargeCarDoorForm _DoorForm
};
```

I can get the doorColor of either object without reimplementing much code at all in LargeCar. 
Now, in my code I have several classes which already inherit from Car, and in my customised code I want them to use the ui in the new LargeCar class. 
For instance, a class using the original Car class:

```
    class AutonomousCar: public Car
    {
    ..
    public:
      void showDoorColour() 
      {
         std::cout << doorColour();          
      }
      .. tons of other functions ..
    };
```

The AutonomousCar class is large with a lot of functionality. If I want a new class with all the functionality of AutonomousCar but the UI of LargeCar, is there a way to use multiple inheritance (or some other design feature) to achieve this?

Comment: I would put all GUI stuff into a separate GUI class and use rather the composition (GUI is the class member variable) than the inheritance. I.e. both AutonomousCar  and LargeCar contain the member variables of GUI class type.

Comment: Usually, compositoin is simpler and easier than inheritance. But for inheritance, usually private inheritance is implementation inheritance, while public inheritance is interface inheritance. So you could create a large car interface, and make a class that inherits publicly from large car interface, and privately from Car or AutonomousCar.

Comment: I believe that both largeCarDoorForm and CarDoorForm descend from QWidget right ?

Comment: largeCarDoorForm and CarDoorForm are classes generated by moc from a ui form text file, and are not related.